# A bizzare unsolvable Google Checkout issue occurs in certain server

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I have a site running in Hostgator shared-hosting account with Google Checkout (GC) working since v1.2 - when the site first gone live, the GC works out-of-the-box.

Recently I moved the site to a VPS server and GC  stopped working with this error:
Google Checkout: Invalid response from Google Checkout server

I thought it couldn’t be an issue with Magento’s Google Checkout integration but the new VPS server or maybe SSL cert that require further testing, so I moved the site back to the shared server (the GC starts working again!), and then setup a test site with a valid SSL cert, a working GC account.

3 weeks had passed still GC wouldn’t work in the VPS server; I have tried/searched/tested all possibilities along with the help from Hostgator’s support, and we have exhausted all options to a point that we believe it has nothing to do with SSL cert setup nor the server configuration.

From the above error and the log from "var/log/payment_googlecheckout" I reckon it couldn’t redirect to checkout.google.com/schema/2

```
<order-processing-support>
<request-initial-auth-details>true</request-initial-auth-details>
</order-processing-support>
</checkout-shopping-cart>
[dir] => out
```

It seems a number of people had experienced the same error before but no one seems to be able to find the cause, and I am starting to think it’s a bug lies on Magento’s Google Checkout module.

If you had this issue before and had it solved, please share. Thanks!

Comment: What version of Magento is the site running now?

Comment: This problem must not really be unsolvable if you're posting a question here... ;)

Comment: It's running on v1.6.2. There had never had issue with every version update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This person](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14573/) seems to have had a similar problem and it was due to an issue with their cURL installation. Have you compared versions from your shared hosting with your VPS? I'd compare: PHP versions, PHP extension versions, `php.ini` settings, and versions of cURL itself.

If none of that bring about any results, open up `app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/Model/Api/Xml/Abstract.php` and modify the `_call()` method like this:

```
// app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/Model/Api/Xml/Abstract.php

public function _call($xml)
{
    // ... snip ...
    $result = @simplexml_load_string($response);
    if (!$result) {
        // Add this...
        Mage::log(var_export($response, true), null, 'google_checkout_debug.log', true);
        // ... end
        $result = simplexml_load_string('<error><error-message>Invalid response from Google Checkout server</error-message></error>');
    }
```

With this, you will have the exact response from Google logged to `var/log/google_checkout_debug.log`. Use this to debug what might be going wrong (perhaps there is another error message embedded in the response).

**Just remember to remove the code when you're done!**

Comment: Thanks! I will try it asap and let you know the result.
Update: The debug message shows: 2012-03-13T00:41:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): ''
I should also mention, there is no error log file in my GC account > Integration Console.

It looks like GC server simply refuses the connection Magento asking.

Comment: The "cURL installation. " was indeed the cause.  As soon as I sent this piece of info to my webhost, they were able to fix it right away.

Comment: Guess it wasn't unsolvable after all ;)

Comment: Yes :) Should had posted my question immediately when the error occurred. There were a bit of blaming game between GC support and webhost and lots of frustration when different support person asked the same question which I had to repeat almost in every email, but overall my webhost was trying their best to assist me. I can't blame them for not catching this as there was no detail log  being recorded in the server nor Magento/var/log. I wonder if Magento GC module could do better to capture the error, e.g. give a more descriptive detail.